# How to make infinite stream (bash) into java args from console?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, stdout

consider the following java program:

```
class PrintName{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hi " + args[0]);
    }
}
```

Now I just compile and execute it from console (I'm on Ubuntu server):

```
~$:javac PrintName.java
~$:java PrintName "Fernando"
```

I get the next output:

```
Hi Fernando
```

I know there are commands like 'yes' in Linux, with which I can get infinite stream of data. My idea is to do something like this:

```
yes "Fernando" | java PrintName >> my_file.txt
```

I want to be able to pass "infinite" Fernando's to my program and have it run infinitely many times, then be able to manipulate the STDO to redirect to some file.

I don't know if I explained it clearly, sorry for my poor handling of the English language. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: But even if you pass "infinite" Fernandos, your java program, in its current shape, will print only the first of them, and discard the rest. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

This is where you want the [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs) command:

```sh
yes Fernando | xargs java PrintName
```

xargs takes each line of stdin, and passes it as command line arguments to the given command.

To redirect it to a file, you can wrap that in a grouping construct:

```sh
{ yes Fernando | xargs java PrintName; } >> my_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly, ¡You are the real MVP!